# Copy objects with different prefixes from AWS S3 bucket to local host will create folders locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Will `aws s3 sync s3://myBucket/this_folder/object_file C:\\Users\Desktop` create also the "this_folder" in C:\Users\Desktop? If not, what would be the solution to copy/sync including the folder structure of S3? I mean I have many files in different S3 bucket folders sorted by year, month, day. I would like to copy them locally with the folder structure/tree to be created locally as it is in the S3 bucket. Thank you.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

> Will aws s3 sync s3://myBucket/this_folder/object_file C:\Users\Desktop create also the "this_folder" in C:\Users\Desktop?

Yes, it will. `aws s3 sync` is recursive by default.

You may want to consider adding the `--delete` option to make sure that the local directory `C:\Users\Desktop` does not have deprecated files that are no longer in the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `aws cli` with the `--recursive` argument.

For example:

```bash
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://your_bucket/your_folder_named_x path/to/your/destination
```